# Store skins on skis between tour?

Tags: gear, gear-care, cross-country-skiing, alpine-touring

Usually, before going on a ski touring expedition, I prepare all the material beforehand to spare as much time as possible outside. This includes installing the skins on the skis while being warm inside (when I know the tour will start with an uphill, which is usually the case).
Unfortunately, last tour got cancelled last minute.

Would it be bad for skins to stay installed on the skis until next tour in at most a couple of weeks ?

Comment: If under tension, I would release the tension. Just helps them keep their shape.

Answer (score 3):

It probably depends on how you store them and for how long. However, given that removing the skins takes like a minute and putting them back on not much longer, I would remove them to avoid any risk. As far as I can see, there are the following potential issues:

- glue might start sticking to the base of your skis. This is especially a problem when stored somewhere warmer
- tension on the skins might deform them (as mentioned by Jon Custer)
- potential buildup of dust and dirt on the skins while being stored